# RoR: Displaying active storage images within an 'each' iteration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to show user profile pics in a loop of tweets.

My models

```
user.rb
has_many :tweets

tweet.rb
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

My view

```
<% @tweets.reverse.each do |tweet| %>
    <strong><%= link_to tweet.user.email, thisuser_path(tweet.user_id) %></strong>
    <br>
    <%= tweets_index_avatar(@image_tweet) %>

   ....

 <% end %>
```

My helper

```
def tweets_index_avatar(image_tweet)
    if user.avatar.attached?
      image_tag user.avatar.variant(resize: "100x100!"), class: "rounded-circle"
      else
      image_tag 'default_avatar.jpg', height: 100, width: 100, class: "rounded-circle"
    end
  end
```

With this (expected)...

```
undefined local variable or method `user'
```

I've tried multiple combinations

```
def tweets_index_avatar(image_tweet)
    if tweet.user.avatar.attached?
      image_tag tweet.user.avatar.variant(resize: "100x100!"), class: "rounded-circle"
      else
      image_tag 'default_avatar.jpg', height: 100, width: 100, class: "rounded-circle"
    end
  end
```

Error

```
undefined local variable or method `tweet' for
```

Or...

```
def tweets_index_avatar(image_tweet)
    if tweet.user_id.avatar.attached?
      image_tag tweet.user_id.avatar.variant(resize: "100x100!"), class: "rounded-circle"
      else
      image_tag 'default_avatar.jpg', height: 100, width: 100, class: "rounded-circle"
    end
  end
```

Same result

My avatars work fine outside my iteration but how would I get them working inside my 'each' iteration?
ty

Comment: What is `@image_tweet`?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "my avatars work fine outside"?

Comment: Outside of "each do" iterations. ("@.....") is the syntax that works for me with my helpers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are passing incorrect param(@image_tweet is not defined) to helper method.  I assume you want to do it as following.

My view

```rb
  <% @tweets.reverse.each do |tweet| %>
    <strong><%= link_to tweet.user.email, thisuser_path(tweet.user_id) %></strong>
    <br>
    <%= tweets_index_avatar(tweet) %>

   ....

  <% end %>
```

My helper

```rb
  def tweets_index_avatar(tweet)
    if tweet.user.avatar.attached?
      image_tag tweet.user.avatar.variant(resize: "100x100!"), class: "rounded-circle"
      else
      image_tag 'default_avatar.jpg', height: 100, width: 100, class: "rounded-circle"
    end
  end
```